# finding files with $hostname_$date +%Y%m%d

Tags: linux, bash

New to bash and trying to figure out how to go about this. Ultimately my problem is trying to declare the variables of $hostname or $date in the find function to grab a specific file.

Essentially I have a script that pulls output from multiple files and appends the info to a file in /somedirectory and assigns it as the HOSTNAME_TODAYSDATE. In the script it is set as

```
myfile="$(hostname)_$(date +%Y%m%d )"
```

I want to write a bash script to find the files with $hostname_$date and rename them to add

```
"_test"
```

at the end (since I only want to rename files that were created on that day)
I also want to write a separate script that will do a diff, lets say between $hostname_$date_test1 and $hostname_$date_test2, and name it diff_$hostname_$date

I tried running some tests just on the CL with variations of

```
find . -type f -name '$(hostname)_$(date +%Y%m%d )' -exec mv {} {}_test \;
```

but it either wouldn't find/rename the file or it would say illegal variable name when I changed things around.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: single quotes are preventing command substitution

Comment: Good point. I've edited the command on the CL but still not getting the new file. I changed it to **find . -type f -name "$HOSTNAME'_'date +%Y%m%d" -exec mv {} {}_posttest \;** no errors show, but the file is not changed

Comment: Because nothing matches; you've included single quotes inside the double-quoted string, and you aren't running `date` anymore, so you are looking for files with a name like `myhost'_'date +%Y%m%d`, not `myhost_20171018`. Use `-name "${HOSTNAME}_$(date +%Y%m%d)"`.